MFA redirect to captive layout Itemid
A user gets redirected to the page component/users/captive?Itemid=xxx to enter the second security code. But this page seams not to be possible to create as a menu item, so the itemid chosen is the home menu item.
The problem is my home menu item is not displaying the body/content component. Its only displaying modules.
If assigning the captive_template which outputs the body/content component it just gets ignored and the template assigned to the redirected Itemid=xxx is used.
How can i configure the itemid/menu item the user gets redirected to when going to component/users/captive ?

How did you make the homepage not display the component?
